How to use async, await, and resolve()
I'm trying to execute query and get the result, and when the query is all done, execute 'sendSoapMessage(soapMessageJson)'. However I find out everytime I run the this program, soapMessageJson is empty. It must be related with the usage of async, await, and resolve(); Any idea on how to solve this issue? I'm quite confused of using this async function. T T
Here is the code. (node.js)
// CSV 파일을 파싱하고 데이터베이스에 저장하는 함수
function parseAndSaveCti(product) {
  const latestFile = getLatestFile(ctiDir, product.fileType); // 가장 최신의 CSV 파일을 찾음
  if (!latestFile) { // 파일이 없는 경우
    console.log('CTI: CSV 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다.');
    return;
  }

  if(product.lastProcessedFile === latestFile){
    console.log(`CTI ${product.name} 파싱 오류: 새로운 파일이 없습니다. 파싱을 종료합니다.`);
    return;
  }

  ctiController.lastProcessedFile = latestFile;

  const latestFilePath = path.join(ctiDir, latestFile); // 최신 파일의 경로를 구성
  console.log(`최신 파일에서 데이터를 파싱 및 저장: ${latestFilePath}`);


  let soapMessageJson = [];
  // CSV 파일을 파싱하고, 데이터베이스에 저장할 데이터를 가져옴
  parseCSVFile(latestFilePath, async (parsedData) => {
    // let soapMessageJson = [];
    if (parsedData.length > 0) { // 데이터가 있는 경우
      for(const row of parsedData){
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
          let { farmNum, houseNum, averTemp, humidity, waterIntake, feedIntake, siloWeight, birdWeight, dateTime } = row;
          let makrId = 'samwoo';
          
          const selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM CTIFARMS WHERE lsindRegistNo = ? AND stallNo = ?`;
          connection.query(selectQuery,[farmNum, houseNum],(err,results)=>{
            if(err){
              console.log('데이터 조회 중 오류:', err);
              return;
            }
            if(results.length>0){
              const result = results[0];
              ctiDestination = result.destination;
              if(result.destination === 'chukpyoungwon'){
                // 각 CSV 열을 데이터베이스 필드에 매핑
                const query = `INSERT INTO CTIBIGDATA (farmNum, houseNum, temperature, humidity, waterIntake, feedIntake, siloWeight, birdWeight, mesureDt)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`;
                // mesureval01=averTemp, 02=humidity 03=hourly water intake 04=hourly feed intake, 05=silo weight, 06=bird scale, mesureDt=dateTime
                // SQL 쿼리를 실행해 데이터베이스에 삽입 
                connection.query(query, [farmNum, houseNum, averTemp, humidity, waterIntake, feedIntake, siloWeight, birdWeight, dateTime], (err) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.error('데이터 삽입 중 오류:', err);
                    return;
                  }
                  console.log('CTI Data has been inserted to DB.');
                  soapMessageJson.push(
                    {
                      lsindRegistNo:farmNum, itemCode:result.itemCode, markId:makrId, eqpmnCode:'ES01', eqpmnEsntlSn:'', eqpmnNo:result.eqpmnNo, 
                      stallTyCode:result.stallTyCode, stallNo:result.stallNo, roomNo:result.roomNo, roomDtlNo:result.roomDtlNo, mesureDt:dateTime, mesureVal01: averTemp,
                      mesureVal02: '', mesureVal03: '', mesureVal04: '', mesureVal05: '', mesureVal06: '', mesureVal07: '', mesureVal08: '', mesureVal09: '', mesureVal10: '',
                      mesureVal11: '', mesureVal12: '', mesureVal13: '', mesureVal14: '', mesureVal15: ''
                    }
                  );
                  soapMessageJson.push(
                    {
                      lsindRegistNo:farmNum, itemCode:result.itemCode, markId:makrId, eqpmnCode:'ES02', eqpmnEsntlSn:'', eqpmnNo:result.eqpmnNo, 
                      stallTyCode:result.stallTyCode, stallNo:result.stallNo, roomNo:result.roomNo, roomDtlNo:result.roomDtlNo, mesureDt:dateTime, mesureVal01: humidity,
                      mesureVal02: '', mesureVal03: '', mesureVal04: '', mesureVal05: '', mesureVal06: '', mesureVal07: '', mesureVal08: '', mesureVal09: '', mesureVal10: '',
                      mesureVal11: '', mesureVal12: '', mesureVal13: '', mesureVal14: '', mesureVal15: ''
                    }
                  );
                  soapMessageJson.push(
                    {
                      lsindRegistNo:farmNum, itemCode:result.itemCode, markId:makrId, eqpmnCode:'AF02', eqpmnEsntlSn:'', eqpmnNo:result.eqpmnNo, 
                      stallTyCode:result.stallTyCode, stallNo:result.stallNo, roomNo:result.roomNo, roomDtlNo:result.roomDtlNo, mesureDt:dateTime, mesureVal01: waterIntake,
                      mesureVal02: '사용량', mesureVal03: '', mesureVal04: '', mesureVal05: '', mesureVal06: '', mesureVal07: '', mesureVal08: '', mesureVal09: '', mesureVal10: '',
                      mesureVal11: '', mesureVal12: '', mesureVal13: '', mesureVal14: '', mesureVal15: ''
                    }
                  );
                  soapMessageJson.push(
                    {
                      lsindRegistNo:farmNum, itemCode:result.itemCode, markId:makrId, eqpmnCode:'AF05', eqpmnEsntlSn:'', eqpmnNo:result.eqpmnNo, 
                      stallTyCode:result.stallTyCode, stallNo:result.stallNo, roomNo:result.roomNo, roomDtlNo:result.roomDtlNo, mesureDt:dateTime, mesureVal01: feedIntake,
                      mesureVal02: '', mesureVal03: '', mesureVal04: '', mesureVal05: '', mesureVal06: '', mesureVal07: '', mesureVal08: '', mesureVal09: '', mesureVal10: '',
                      mesureVal11: '', mesureVal12: '', mesureVal13: '', mesureVal14: '', mesureVal15: ''
                    }
                  );
                  soapMessageJson.push(
                    {
                      lsindRegistNo:farmNum, itemCode:result.itemCode, markId:makrId, eqpmnCode:'AF01', eqpmnEsntlSn:'', eqpmnNo:result.eqpmnNo, 
                      stallTyCode:result.stallTyCode, stallNo:result.stallNo, roomNo:result.roomNo, roomDtlNo:result.roomDtlNo, mesureDt:dateTime, mesureVal01: siloWeight,
                      mesureVal02: '', mesureVal03: '', mesureVal04: '', mesureVal05: '', mesureVal06: '', mesureVal07: '', mesureVal08: '', mesureVal09: '', mesureVal10: '',
                      mesureVal11: '', mesureVal12: '', mesureVal13: '', mesureVal14: '', mesureVal15: ''
                    }
                  );
                  soapMessageJson.push({
                      lsindRegistNo:farmNum, itemCode:result.itemCode, markId:makrId, eqpmnCode:'PC07', eqpmnEsntlSn:'', eqpmnNo:result.eqpmnNo, 
                      stallTyCode:result.stallTyCode, stallNo:result.stallNo, roomNo:result.roomNo, roomDtlNo:result.roomDtlNo, mesureDt:dateTime, mesureVal01: birdWeight,
                      mesureVal02: '', mesureVal03: '', mesureVal04: '', mesureVal05: '', mesureVal06: '', mesureVal07: '', mesureVal08: '', mesureVal09: '', mesureVal10: '',
                      mesureVal11: '', mesureVal12: '', mesureVal13: '', mesureVal14: '', mesureVal15: ''
                  });
                  // resolve();

                  // console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: ',soapMessageJson);
                });
              }else{
                console.log('destination: ', result.destination);
                console.log('No data sending is needed. terminating process.');
                // resolve();
              }

            }
          });

          resolve();
        });
      }
      console.log('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb:',soapMessageJson);
      sendSoapMessage(soapMessageJson);
    }
  });
}


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There are many irrelevant lines but the code is truncated. What is "connection"? You need to avoid callbacks and use promisified version of whatever db client you use, so you could do  await connection.query(...) without "new Promise", this results in cleaner control flow. Why are there commented resolve()? This is the right place to use them. Uncommented resolve() is wrong and can cause empty array.

What is parseCSVFile and how is soapMessageJson used? It needs to be wrapped with new Promise and awaited before using soapMessageJson (its callback is called multiple times so it cannot be promisified as straightforward as connection.query). parseAndSaveCti should be async and return a promise, asynchronicity is contagious, currently you seem to have this problem with it https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321

The problem is that your code doesn't wait for the inner call of connection.query to execute the callback function that is given to it.
To solve this, it will be more elegant to promisify the functions that take asynchronously executed callback functions. Then you can flatten your code using await.
Here is how that could work:
// Promisify asynchronous callback functions
const queryPromise = (connection, sqlQuery, params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    connection.query(sqlQuery, params, (err, results) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(results))
);

const parseCSVFilePromise = (path) => new Promise((resolve) => 
    parseCSVFile(path, resolve)
);

// Make function async
async function parseAndSaveCti(product) {
  const latestFile = getLatestFile(ctiDir, product.fileType);
  if (!latestFile) {
    console.log('CTI: CSV File not found.');
    return;
  }

  if (product.lastProcessedFile === latestFile){
    console.log(`CTI ${product.name} parsing error: No new files found. Terminate parsing.`);
    return;
  }

  ctiController.lastProcessedFile = latestFile;
  const latestFilePath = path.join(ctiDir, latestFile);
  const parsedData = await parseCSVFilePromise(latestFilePath);
  const soapMessageJson = [];
  for (const row of parsedData) {
    const { farmNum, houseNum, averTemp, humidity, waterIntake, feedIntake, siloWeight, birdWeight, dateTime } = row;
    const selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM CTIFARMS WHERE lsindRegistNo = ? AND stallNo = ?`;
    let results;
    try {
      results = await queryPromise(connection, selectQuery, [farmNum, houseNum]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error during data selection:', err);
      return;
    }
    const ctiDestination = results[0]?.destination;
    if (ctiDestination !== 'chukpyoungwon') {
      console.log('destination: ', ctiDestination, '. No data sending is needed. Skipping.');
      continue;
    }
    const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO CTIBIGDATA (farmNum, houseNum, temperature, humidity, waterIntake,
                                                 feedIntake, siloWeight, birdWeight, mesureDt)
                         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`;
    try {
      await queryPromise(connection, insertQuery, [farmNum, houseNum, averTemp, humidity, waterIntake, 
                                                   feedIntake, siloWeight, birdWeight, dateTime]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error during data insertion:', err);
      return;
    }
    // Add your objects to insert here (I omitted them here as not relevant to the fix)
    soapMessageJson.push( { lsindRegistNo:farmNum, ......... },
                          { lsindRegistNo:farmNum, ......... },
                          { lsindRegistNo:farmNum, ......... },
                          // ...
                        );
  }
  if (soapMessageJson.length) sendSoapMessage(soapMessageJson);
}

I couldn't test this code as there are several unknowns in your code, including getLatestFile, ctiDir, ctiController, path, connection, sendSoapMessage.

Any feedback on this answer, @ChihyunAhn?
